# how to disable images in webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

in vb.net 2003  ,  how to disable images loading in webbrowser control

Comment: Do you want to prevent all images or just ones with the <img> tags?

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this in the past is using Regex to replace image tags with empty quotes. Give the following a try, stick it into your DocumentLoaded event, or such:

```
origHTML = webBrowser.DocumentText
Dim newHTML as String

Dim regex as String = "<img.*/>"

newHTML = Regex.Replace(origHTML, regex, "", RegexOptions.Multiline)
webBrowser.DocumentText = newHTML
```

This should solve your problem.

Best Regards

Comment: This blocked most of my images, but let a few through. The original regex fails if the terminating > character is on a different line and it always fails if <img is not in lowercase. Also it uses greedy mode which means it matches on the last > character rather than the first, which means it can replace more than you want.

So I tweaked the expression a little to "<img.*?>" and to use the options RegexOptions.SingleLine | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

This works better (for me), but of course I can not guarantee that I have not overlooked some other scenario.

Comment: This solution would remove image tags in the scraped HTML code, but images would still load in the WebBrowser control. How do you enable the option to not load images in the control so that pages load faster?